# "Riffle" two strings

Tags: string-manipulation

I have two strings, e.g.,  `s1="A|P|Q|Z"` and `s2="r|ss|t|yy"`, where `"|"` is meant to be a separator. I would like to get the result as another string `s=Ar|Pss|Qt|Zyy` by joining the corresponding parts of the two strings `s1` and `s2` as indicated by the separators. What would be a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
StringSplit[{s1, s2}, "|"] // Transpose // StringRiffle[#, "|", ""] &
```

Comment: Clean and elegant (+1).